# R: Visual where date is broken up by category

Tags: r

I have a following data set that I collected (real data set is much larger):

```
DATE;TIME;TAG
20.3.2017;0:01;HAR
20.3.2017;16:05;JKT
20.3.2017;16:26;RVA
20.3.2017;18:35;JKT
20.3.2017;19:43;JVA
20.3.2017;20:00;PER
20.3.2017;21:42;RVA
20.3.2017;22:05;HAR
20.3.2017;23:59;HAR
```

First I calculated actual time stamps as following

```
dataset$timestamp <- with(dataset, ISOdatetime(substring(dataset$DATE, 1, 4),substring(dataset$DATE, 7, 7),substring(dataset$DATE, 9, 10),substring(dataset$TIME,1,regexpr(':', dataset$TIME)-1),substring(dataset$TIME,regexpr(':', dataset$TIME)+1,length(dataset$TIME)),0))
```

As you might notice there is only one tag active at any given moment. I would like to visualize this in following diagram.

Think about a matrix that is 1440 units high (minutes in day) and 28 units wide (days in my data set). Each square is colored depending on what TAG was active during that minute.

Is there a way to do this in R or do I need to use some other visualization tool?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are not asking how to process your data into an appropriate format, but just how to produce the graph. there are several possibilities, for instance using `ggplot2`:

```
#generate some toy data
toyDf <- data.frame(minute = sample(1440, 100, TRUE),
                    day = sample(28,100,TRUE),
                    tag = sample(c("foo","bar","baz"),100,TRUE))

#plot
library(ggplot2)
# specify data, x, and y:
ggplot(toyDf, aes(day,minute)) +
# specify plot type and fill colour levels:  
  geom_raster(aes(fill = tag),hjust=0, vjust=0) +
# specify where to draw minor gridlines:
  scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(1, 28, 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(1, 1440, 1)) +
#set plot aspect ratio (because it will be very high):
  theme(aspect.ratio=30/5,
#tweak some visual elements (gridlines, background):
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="black", size=0.05),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

Comment: This code gives me following error: 

    Error in if (is.waive(data) || empty(data)) return(cbind(data, PANEL = integer(0))) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: sorry! i forgot to rename my original `df` to `toyDf` in the ggplot call.